# iterating through a list in racket

Tags: racket

```
(define list45 (map number->string(build-list 1000 values)))
list45
(first (list45))
(rest (list45))
```

ERROR:
    application: not a procedure;
     expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments

I am trying to iterate through the list that i converted to strings. to do that i tried to use the first and rest functions to view everything in the list. Why am i getting errors for this?

Thanks

Comment: Don't put `list45` between parentheses. It's `(first list45)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drop the parentheses around the list:

```
(first list45)
=> "0"

(rest  list45)
=> '("1" "2" … "998" "999")
```

In Scheme, when you surround something between `()`, the interpreter evaluates that as a function application with no arguments. Given that `list45` is not a function, the "application: not a procedure" error is raised. In Racket is very easy to iterate over the list:

```
(for ([e (in-list list45)])
  (displayln e))
```

But if for some reason you want to use `first` and `rest` to traverse the list, here's one possibility, using explicit recursion:

```
(define (iterate lst)
  (unless (empty? lst)
    (displayln (first lst))
    (iterate (rest lst))))

(iterate list45)
```